# How to send multiple tags as an array in a single text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a column of tags[] type array and for now, I'm sending multiple values of the array by

```html
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :tags %>
    <%= form.text_field :tags, name: "vacancy[tags][]" %>
    <%= form.text_field :tags, name: "vacancy[tags][]" %>
    <%= form.text_field :tags, name: "vacancy[tags][]" %>
  </div>
```

but I don't want to use multiple text_fields  for multiple array values is there any way to send multiple array values in just one text_field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should look at multiselect input with dynamic creation options like select2: https://select2.org/tagging#tagging-with-multi-value-select-boxes

Comment: you mean   <%= form.select :tags,['Ruby','Node'],{prompt:'Ruby'},{class: "form-control", multiple: "multiple"}%>
but i dont want  has specific values user can add any tags.

Comment: Yes. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/djrxoyp3/ 
Just put any data in the input field and press enter